# How can i interleave elements of 2 lists in scala

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'd like to combine two Lists of arbitrary length in such a way that elements from the 2nd List are inserted after every n-th element into the 1st List. If the 1st List length is less than n, no insertion results.

So having

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
val b = List(101,102,103)
val n = 3
```

I want the resulting List to look like this:

```
List(1,2,3,101,4,5,6,102,7,8,9,103,10,11,12,13,14,15)
```

I have this working using a `foldLeft` on `a`, but I'm wondering how the same logic could be accomplished using Scalaz?

Thanks for everyone's answers. They were all helpful to me !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meet my apomorphism friend

```
def apo[A, B](v: B)(f: B => Option[(A, Either[B, List[A]])]): List[A] = f(v) match {
   case None => Nil
   case Some((a, Left(b)))   => a :: apo(b)(f)
   case Some((a, Right(as))) => a :: as 
}
```

Your interleave method can be implemented like this

```
def interleave[A](period: Int, substitutes: List[A], elems: List[A]): List[A] =
  apo((period, substitutes, elems)){
    case (_, _, Nil)       => None
    case (_, Nil, v :: vs) => Some((v, Right(vs)))
    case (0, x :: xs, vs)  => Some((x, Left((period, xs, vs))))
    case (n, xs, v :: vs)  => Some((v, Left((n - 1, xs, vs))))  
  }
```

This gives:

```
scala> interleave(3, b, a)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103 , 10, 11 , 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

The good point is the computation ends when a or b are Nil unlike foldLeft. The bad news is interleave is no more tail recursive

Comment: Interesting. If i understand the term correctly, apomorhism and tail recursion are sort of mutually-exclusive ?

Comment: Right. You may have SOE with "thousands sized" lists. Note with your example, apomorphism is more efficient than catamorphism (foldLeft) because it'll stop just after b list turns to Nil

Answer (score 5):

This gets very simple with `zipAll`. Moreover, you are able to choose the amount of elements of the second array (in this case 1):

```
val middle = b.grouped(1).toList
val res = a.grouped(n).toList.zipAll(middle, Nil, Nil)
res.filterNot(_._1.isEmpty).flatMap(x => x._1 ++ x._2)
```

Or if you prefer, one-liner:

```
a.grouped(n).toList.zipAll(b.map(List(_)), Nil, Nil).filterNot(_._1.isEmpty).flatMap(x => x._1 ++ x._2)
```

You can also make an implicit class, so you could call `a.interleave(b, 3)` or with an optional thrid parameter `a.interleave(b, 3, 1)`.

Comment: I have posted one more alternative answer.

Comment: Seems like the cleanest - Are there any pitfalls to this compared to a fold or direct recursion ? I think it might be in between fold and recursion in terms of performance

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
 def process[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = 
   if(xs.size <= n || ys.size == 0) xs
   else xs.take(n):::ys.head::process(xs.drop(n),ys.tail,n)
```

---

```
scala> process(a,b,n) 
res8: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) 
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

scala> process(a,b,n) 
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103, 10, 11)

scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> process(a,b,n) 
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> process(a,b,n) 
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8)
```

---

Your request is "If the 1st List length is less than n, no insertion results", then my code should change to:

```
 def process[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = 
   if(xs.size < n || ys.size == 0) xs
   else xs.take(n):::ys.head::process(xs.drop(n),ys.tail,n)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
def interleave[A](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[A], n: Int): Seq[A] = {
  val iter = xs grouped n
  val coll = iter zip ys.iterator flatMap { case (xs, y) => if (xs.size == n) xs :+ y else xs }
  (coll ++ iter.flatten).toIndexedSeq
}

scala> interleave(a, b, n)
res34: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

scala> interleave(1 to 2, b, n)
res35: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2)

scala> interleave(1 to 6, b, n)
res36: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102)

scala> interleave(1 to 7 b, n)
res37: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7)

scala> interleave(1 to 7, Nil, n)
res38: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> interleave(1 to 7, Nil, -3)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: size=-3 and step=-3, but both must be positive
```

It is short, but it is not the most efficient solution. If you call it with Lists for example, the append-operations (`:+` and `++`) are expensive (`O(n)`).

EDIT: I'm sorry. I notice now, that you want to have a solution with Scalaz. Nevertheless the answer may be useful therefore I won't delete it.

Comment: And your solution didnot performance correctly if a.size > 3(b.size+1)

Comment: @Antoras: Yeah i was looking for a more elegant solution than mine using `foldLeft`. Yours works for the example. However, and it is my fault for picking a bad example, the lists could be of arbitrary length. So `a.grouped(n).length` won't necessarily equal `b.length`

Comment: @marcin: Changed my code a little bit. Hopefully, it works now as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Without Scalaz and recursion.

```
scala> a.grouped(n).zip(b.iterator.map{ Some(_) } ++ Iterator.continually(None)).flatMap{ case (as, e) => if (as.size == n) as ++ e else as }.toList
res17: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Generic way:

```
def filled[T, A, That](a: A, b: Seq[T], n: Int)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[A, T, That], a2seq: A => Seq[T]): That = {
  val builder = bf()
  builder.sizeHint(a, a.length / n)
  builder ++= a.grouped(n).zip(b.iterator.map{ Some(_) } ++ Iterator.continually(None)).flatMap{ case (as, e) => if(as.size == n ) as ++ e else as }
  builder.result()
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> filled("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "1234", 3)
res0: String = abc1def2ghi3jkl4mnopqrstuvwxyz

scala> filled(1 to 15, 101 to 103, 3)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 102, 7, 8, 9, 103, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

scala> filled(1 to 3, 101 to 103, 3)
res70: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 101)

scala> filled(1 to 2, 101 to 103, 3)
res71: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
```

Comment: `map+flatten` is the same as `flatMap`

Comment: @senia: i like the padding with None idea, clever. However if `a.length` is less than n, the insertion will occur. I want it to occur only if `a.length >= n`

Comment: @marcin, It's hard to express such complex logic thru compositionally. It's better to go for recursion/loops in such cases IMO.

Answer (score 0):

here's the one you want:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
final def interleave[A](base: Vector[A], a: List[A], b: List[A]): Vector[A] = a match {
  case elt :: aTail => interleave(base :+ elt, b, aTail)
  case _ => base ++ b
}

...

interleave(Vector.empty, a, b)
```